How do I find confidence interval and what do I do with confirmation points?
I'm running a face-centered composite design with confirmation points. Am I correct in my assumption that the "S" I get from Minitab can be used to calculate CI? If not, how do I get the CI? And what to do with the confirmation points? I've now read that the values at the confirmation points should ideally sit inside the prediction interval, not the CI. How do I get the prediction interval? What does it mean if half of the values eventually happen to fall outside the prediction interval?

